# How to perform regex on Get-xxx cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error | ?{$_.EventID -eq 6008} | Sort Message -unique
```

I get the output : [image]

I want this ouput : [image]

How should I do to apply regex match on this query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this(needs PS3+):

```powershell
Get-EventLog -LogName System -EntryType Error | 
    ?{$_.EventID -eq 6008} | Sort Message -unique | 
    ft Index,TimeGenerated,EntryType,Source,InstanceID,
    @{n="Message";e={[regex]::Matches($_.Message, "\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}").Value}}
```